# TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address) view external returns (uint256))

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

`` `why compile time getting error:: TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address) view external returns (uint256)) ``

`I want to assign ERC20 token address to token variable then Deposit function using token balance Of getting error why?? here is my code`

`pragma solidity ^0.8.17;`

`interface IERC20 {`
`/**`
`* @dev Emitted when value tokens are moved from one account (from) to`
`* another (to).`
`*`
`* Note that value may be zero.`
`*/`
`event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`

```
/**
 * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
 * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
 */
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

/**
 * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
 */
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

/**
 * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
 */
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

/**
 * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `to`.
 *
 * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event.
 */
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

/**
 * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
 * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
 * zero by default.
 *
 * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
 */
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

/**
 * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
 *
 * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
 * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
 * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
 * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
 * desired value afterwards:
 * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
 *
 * Emits an {Approval} event.
 */
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

/**
 * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `from` to `to` using the
 * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
 * allowance.
 *
 * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event.
 */
function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) external returns (bool);
```

`}`

`contract VeloxWrapper {`
`address payable owner;`
`IERC20 public token;`

```
event Withdrawal(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
event Deposit(address indexed from, uint256 amount);

constructor(address tokenAddress) payable {
    token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
}

receive() external payable {
        token.balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function totalBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
    return token.balanceOf(address(this));
}

function withdraw(uint withdrawalAmount) public {
    require(token.balanceOf[msg.sender] >= withdrawalAmount);
    token.balanceOf[msg.sender] -= withdrawalAmount;
    msg.sender.transfer(withdrawalAmount);
    Withdrawal(msg.sender, withdrawalAmount);}
```

`}`

Comment: token.balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value; at recevier function getting error

Comment: require(token.balanceOf[msg.sender] >= withdrawalAmount);
    token.balanceOf[msg.sender] -= withdrawalAmount;                                                                                                      in withdrawral function

Comment: remove the comments and make your code more readable